# Code to generate hexadecimal values of all colors

Tags: php, colors, hex

Hi guys I need to generate a list of all possible 16 million colors in the 6 digit hexadecimal notation - how can that be done, I would appreciate a formula for that. I'm building the script in php here.

Comment: If you can count, and you can use [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php), there's no further algorithm necessary.

Comment: Well I haven't actually used hexadecimal notation much except in CSS styles so was a bit lost when it came to coding it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just print all values from 0 to 2^24 and format it as hex with 6 digits...

```
long max = pow(2,24);
for(long i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
printf("%6x\n", i);
}
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i = 0 to 16 million
    print i as hexa
```